# How to make a Windows 7 Bootable VHD?

Tags: windows-7, windows, vhd

Is there an easy way to understand how to make a Windows 7 Bootable `.VHD`? The ones I've found are a little over me.

Answer (score 0):

Had this question from a client a couple of weeks ago, sent them [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2953-virtual-hard-drive-vhd-file-create-start-boot.html) link and they did it them selves (Less work for me)

> While all Windows 7 editions can create and attach a VHD, only the Windows 7 Ultimate and Enterprise editions support booting from a VHD.